# ARC forbids synthesizing a proper with unspecified ownership etc. but only for me

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, synthesize

I'm working on an iPhone with a group of people over github. I was added to the project late and just started today. I am unable to build the project which I find extremely annoying. The reason is that Arc forbids synthesizing a property of an objective-c object  with unspecified ownership or storage attribute. There 8 errors like this preventing building and over 300 warnings that turn into errors as I fix the errors, i.e. if I were to fix 3 of the 8 errors 3 of the 300 warnings would replace them as errors. So while I could go through and add weak or strong to all these many properties throughout the project it'd be a tad tedious and I'm not entirely sure that it'd be good for the project. The other people I'm working with are surprised I'm having errors and are able to build it. My question is how the heck can they build it? is there a setting somewhere that changes the default from assign to strong or something? thanks in advance this is driving me crazy.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? What about them?

Comment: If it's the warning I think it is, I think that warning is a bug, and it might have been fixed in a later version of Xcode. (Properties of object type are supposed to default to strong)

Comment: Huh alright. I see 4.4 is out now so I guess I'll try updating to that and hopefully that's all it takes. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: yup the update worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, this issue is resolved in Xcode 4.4.